# core plot set legend plotsymbol different then plot

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

Hey core plot friends,

i have two plots with plot points. they can have a plotsymbol or not.

the problem is: if the last point in my plot has a hidden plotsymbol, the plotpoint of my legend gets also hidden. Thats why I'm searching for any solution to fix that.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that I have to define the `CPTPlotSymbol` and it styles twice.
Once in the methode of my legend (for me it's the init methode where I load the graph, plots and all styles). Thats where the legend takes the settings from. And the second time in my `symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:`methode for each plotpoint in my plots.